# calculating tf_idf for fvt table

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nlp, tf-idf

I have a frequency value table like-

```
    a   b           
1   3   0                   
2   0   3                   
3   4   5
```

and I want to calculate the tf_idf.

My code-

```
l=len(data)
for doc in data:

m=data.groupby(doc).apply(lambda column: column.sum()/(column != 0).sum())
for i in range(l):
    tf=print(data.loc[i,doc])
    idf=log(l/m)                  
    weight=tf*idf
    data.loc[i,doc]=weight
```

Explanation-
First I am iterating through each column where I am finding the non zero rows in that column in var m and storing the particular value of that row in column as tf and then calculating the tf_idf and replacing the values in table with tf_idf weights.

expected output-

for column g first row we have tf=3 idf=log(5/4) therefore tf_idf=idf*tf

```
    a   b           
1   0.4 0                   
2   0   0.4                 
3   0.17 .22
```

Comment: Please clarify what is `data` and mention your expected output.

Comment: Still confused about `doc` and `data`? Please clarify it. It would be kind if you mention complete expected output for your data.

Comment: @AbdurRehman doc is the iterator in the for loop and I have provided sample for the data dataframe in the question

Comment: In your example, as for as I am understanding, you have 3 documents. Word `a` appears `3-times` in first `doc` and there are total 3-words (a=3 + b=0) in first document so `tf` will be `3/3 = 1`. Since, there are total 3 documents and word `a` appearing in two of them so `idf` will be l`og(3/2) = 0.176` and now `tf-idf = 1 * 0.176 = 0.176`. How did you get `1.2` for a in first document.

Comment: I viewed the example of `tf-idf` from quora. Have a look at here: https://www.quora.com/How-does-TF-IDF-work

Comment: @AbdurRehman I am referencing this http://www.tfidf.com/    here its mentioned tf is the frequency of the word in the document/no of words in the document...since the data is a fvt the values are the freq of the word in the doc..therefore in the first case freq is 3 no of words in first doc is 1 tf=3/1 idf is ln(3/2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186235/discussion-between-abdur-rehman-and-ubuntu-noob).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input DataFrame:

```
df
    a   b
0   3   0
1   0   3
2   4   5
```

First, find `idf` of all words,

```
idf_list = []
for col in list(df.columns):
    total_count = df[col].nonzero()[0][1]
    idf = np.log(len(df) / total_count)
    idf_list.append(round(idf, 3))
```

Now, find `tf-idf` and update the dataframe,

```
for row in range(len(df)):
    total_doc_words = sum(df.iloc[row].values)
    for col in range(len(df.columns)):
        tf = df.iloc[row, col] / total_doc_words
        df.iloc[row, col] = tf * idf_list[col]
```

Output:

```
df
       a    b
0   0.405   0.000
1   0.000   0.405
2   0.180   0.225
```